# Issue with nested for loop incrementing

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, increment

I have collected some online behavioral data and must analyze it using R. When downloading the data, there is no unique identifier for each participant other than the date. Since I am analyzing all the data, I have written a for loop that merges all the CSVs into one data frame, and I would like to add a 'participant' column that increments by 1 for every file that is loaded (e.g. pp1, pp2, pp3). This is what I have so far:

```
OnExpDir = dir()
#Files begin with "PARTICIPANT" but no ID
OnExpList=grep("PARTICIPANT", OnExpDir, value = T)

#Binding data to one table
OnExpData=NULL
for(myfile in OnExpList)
{
  fullExpFileName = paste(getwd(), "/", myfile, sep = "")
  TMPData = read.csv(fullExpFileName, header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)
  #Attempting to add a participant ID
  for(i in 1:length(OnExpList))
  {
    TMPData$pp[i] = paste("pp",i)
  }
  OnExpData = rbind(OnExpData, TMPData)
}
```

Which yields the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         data        |        pp        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data1      |         pp1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data2      |         pp2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data3      |         pp3      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data1      |         pp1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data2      |         pp2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data3      |         pp3      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

However, this is not what I want. It should be more along the lines of:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         data        |        pp        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data1      |         pp1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data2      |         pp1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data3      |         pp1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data1      |         pp2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data2      |         pp2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          data3      |         pp2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

etc.

My apologies if the explanation was not clear. If anyone could help me understand what is wrong with my code, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
OnExpData <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) transform(read.csv(x), 
                      pp = paste0('pp', y)), 
                      paste0(getwd(), "/", OnExpList), seq_along(OnExpList)))
```

Or a shorter using `map_df` from `purrr` :

```
purrr::map_df(paste0(getwd(), "/", OnExpList), read.csv, .id = "pp")
```